# How can I refesh Tk Scale slider position when value variable is changing?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to figure out how to refresh some slider's position in a Tkinter frame when Scale's value is changing.
All the examples I have found are working in the opposite way: refreshing value when the slider's position is changing.
Here is my attempt to code it but even if value is changing nothing is refreshed on my frame (MyWindow):

```
scale = Scale(MyWindow, from_=0, to_=40, length=200, tickinterval=5, state="active")
scale.place(x=700, y=120)
def refreshscale():
    scale.set(value)
    MyWindow.after(100,refreshscale)
refreshscale()
```

What's wrong with this code and how would you refesh the widget when scale value is changing ?

Comment: Your code doesn't show what `value` is. Are you certain that `value` is changing? When I modify your code enough to make it run, and configure it so that `value` changes over time, your code works just fine -- I see the scale moving as the value changes. It would help if you were to [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can deduce from your question a slightly modified version of your code works perfectly. however, if this is not what you are looking for reword the question and I will see what I can do.

```
from tkinter import *
MyWindow = Tk()
value = 0

scale = Scale(MyWindow, from_=0, to_=40, length=200, tickinterval=5, state="active")
scale.place(x=700, y=120)

def refreshscale():
    scale.set(value)
    MyWindow.after(100,refreshscale)

refreshscale()
```